# How do you not print the error statement when using logical operators in Bash?

Tags: bash, logical-operators

Say I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git -v || echo "You don't have Git!"
```

The point of this script would be to check if the user has git or not and display if they don't. Inside this script, if the user who runs it doesn't have git, not only will it display, "You don't have Git!", but it would also display an error message saying:

```
git: command not found
```

Is there any method to use logical operators in bash to simulate a try-catch/try-except statement where it won't display the error message unless told to do so in the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect `stderr` (the error stream) to `/dev/null`:

```
git -v 2>/dev/null || echo "You don't have Git!"
```

Another option is to get the actual path to the `git` command:

```
if gitcmd=$(command -v git)
then
    echo "Git is at $gitcmd"
else
    echo "You don't have Git!"
fi
```

Comment: @Charles It seems `command -v` does not print an error in case `git` isn't found so I removed the redirect.

Comment: Ahh! Sorry, I didn't realize that was intentional. Rolling back to your earlier edit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy All's well, I learned something, thanks!